# Compulab Utilite Pro: searching for not discontinued Linux operating system

Tags: operating-system, embedded-systems

The [Utilite Pro from Compulab](https://www.compulabnordic.dk/product/utl-c1200qm-d2g-nd32-e2-ld-wb-acc/) is a small form-factor ARM computer that seems to have been discontinued, so it is difficult to find **not outdated *NIX (Linux-like) operating systems** that can be run on it.

Could someone please address me to a **minimally recent** one?

Comment: Indeed, as for today (January 2020), there are no more Kali images for Compulab Utilite at the ARM Download site: https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-arm-images/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Kali also works.  I'm running it on the two utilite pro machines I have without issues: https://www.kali.org/docs/arm/utilite-pro/

Answer (score 0):

Arch Linux seems to be (as of December 2019) a maintained project for your Utilite.

- Installation [instructions](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/freescale/utilite).
- [Downloads](http://de4.mirror.archlinuxarm.org/os/) directory.